# $Ind_H^G(\pi\oplus \mu) \simeq Ind_H^G(\pi)\oplus Ind_H^G(\mu)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $\pi$ and $\mu$ be representations of a subgorup $H\leq G$. ($G$ a finite group.) My question is whether or not it is true that
$$
Ind_H^G(\pi\oplus \mu) \simeq Ind_H^G(\pi)\oplus Ind_H^G(\mu)
$$
That is, is the induction of the direct sum of two representations equal to the direct sum of the induced representations?

I have been working with inducing irreducible representations, but I want to understand how how induce representations that are not irreducible (so are direct sums of irreducibles). I was hoping the above would hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. One way to get it for free is to note that both sides have the same universal property:

A map of $G$-modules out of $\text{Ind}_H^G (\pi \oplus \mu)$ into some  $G$-representation $\rho$ is, by definition of $\text{Ind}$, a map of $\pi \oplus \mu$ in the category of $H$-representations to  $\rho$ (viewed as an $H$ representation.)
By the universal property of the direct sum, this is a pair of maps of $H$-representations, one from $\pi$ to $\rho$ and one from $\mu$ to $\rho$. By the universal property of induction again, this is a pair of map from $G$-representations to $\rho$, which, by the universal property of sums again, is a map from the right hand side to $\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" definition of induction is $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G M := kG \otimes_{kH} M$. Once you know $kG$ is a free $kH$-module, the coset-based definition follows immediately. In any case, tensor products are naturally bilinear, giving your result immediately.